# Merging dataframes by using 2 identifiers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes and I would would like to add the data from the 2nd one to the first one such that I get the 3rd dataframe below:

1st dataframe:

```
 dict = [{'name': 'aapl', 'date': '2016-11-29'},
 {'name': 'msft', 'date': '2016-11-29'},
 {'name': 'ge', 'date': '2016-11-29'},
 {'name': 'jpm', 'date': '2016-11-29'},
 {'name': 'aapl', 'date': '2016-11-30'},
 {'name': 'msft', 'date': '2016-11-30'},
 {'name': 'ge', 'date': '2016-11-30'},
 {'name': 'jpm', 'date': '2016-11-30'}]
 df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict)
```

2nd dataframe:

```
 dict = [{'2016-11-29': 'x1', '2016-11-30': 'y1'},
 {'2016-11-29': 'x2','2016-11-30': 'y2'},
 {'2016-11-29': 'x3','2016-11-30': 'y3'},
 {'2016-11-29': 'x4','2016-11-30': 'y4'}]
 df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict, index=['aapl', 'msft','ge','jpm'])
```

3rd Dataframe (target):

```
dict = [{'name': 'aapl', 'date': '2016-11-29', 'df2': 'x1'},
 {'name': 'msft', 'date': '2016-11-29', 'df2': 'x2'},
 {'name': 'ge', 'date': '2016-11-29', 'df2': 'x3'},
 {'name': 'jpm', 'date': '2016-11-29', 'df2': 'x4'},
 {'name': 'aapl', 'date': '2016-11-30', 'df2': 'y1'},
 {'name': 'msft', 'date': '2016-11-30', 'df2': 'y2'},
 {'name': 'ge', 'date': '2016-11-30', 'df2': 'y3'},
 {'name': 'jpm', 'date': '2016-11-30', 'df2': 'y4'}]
 df3 = pd.DataFrame(dict)
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `melt` before `merge`

```
newdf2=df2.reset_index().melt('index').rename(columns={'index':'name','variable':'date'})

df3=df1.merge(newdf2,how='left')
df3
         date  name value
0  2016-11-29  aapl    x1
1  2016-11-29  msft    x2
2  2016-11-29    ge    x3
3  2016-11-29   jpm    x4
4  2016-11-30  aapl    y1
5  2016-11-30  msft    y2
6  2016-11-30    ge    y3
7  2016-11-30   jpm    y4
```

Comment: Fantastic!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Tartaglia yw :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
new_df = df1.merge(df2.unstack().to_frame('df2'), left_on=['date','name'], right_index=True)

>>>new_df
         date  name df2
0  2016-11-29  aapl  x1
1  2016-11-29  msft  x2
2  2016-11-29    ge  x3
3  2016-11-29   jpm  x4
4  2016-11-30  aapl  y1
5  2016-11-30  msft  y2
6  2016-11-30    ge  y3
7  2016-11-30   jpm  y4
```

This works because when you unstack `df2`:

```
df2.unstack().to_frame('df2')
                df2
2016-11-29 aapl  x1
           msft  x2
           ge    x3
           jpm   x4
2016-11-30 aapl  y1
           msft  y2
           ge    y3
           jpm   y4
```

the index is mergeable on the `date` and `name` columns of `df1`